Unable to display image on ASP.NET Core Razor page
I upload a selected image to wwwroot folder. That works.
I return the Razor page with a ViewData containing the path. That doesn't work.
This is what shows when I debug ViewData in immediate debug window:
?ViewData["Uploaded"]
"~/images/DanceImages/bulltrout.jpg"

If I paste that path exactly into an img tag, it works:
<img src="~/images/DanceImages/bulltrout.jpg" alt="" />

But if I try to reference the ViewData["Uploaded"] on the Razor page, I just get the path displayed:
html:
@ViewData["Uploaded"].ToString()

displays this string:
~/images/DanceImages/bulltrout.jpg

So I tried using url.content syntax :
 @Url.Content(ViewData["Uploaded"].ToString())

and I get the path displayed again but without the ~/.
To summarize: the actual string cut from inside the ViewData object when used with <img> tag works.
Screenshot below has hardcoded path that works.
Then next is url.content result
Then finally img tag result
I can't seem to reference the ViewData["Uploaded"] on the Razor page.


Could you pls corret me if I misunderstood your issue? In my test, I'm able to get the image which stored in wwwroot/image folder in my application.

Using Url.Content() is an effective way to generate the correct URL for static files stored in the wwwroot folder. Here's my test:
<img src="/image/Untitled.png" />
<img src="~/image/Untitled.png" />
<h>@ViewData["imageUrl"]</h>
<img src=@ViewData["imageUrl"] />
<img src="@Url.Content("~/image/Untitled.png")" alt="Example Image" />
<img src="@Url.Content(ViewData["imageUrl"].ToString())" alt="Example Image" />

public IActionResult Index()
{
    ViewData["imageUrl"] = "/image/Untitled.png";
    return View();
}



The tilde character ~ is used by Razor, tag helpers and Url.Content helpers to resolve the web application's root. When you use it in paths, it indicates that the path should be considered relative to the root of the application, rather than relative to the current page or folder.
If you assign a path containing a tilde to a literal string, it will be rendered literally at runtime. It will not get processed by the framework. That's why it doesn't work as expected when you include it as part of a value you assign to ViewData.
As you have discovered, if you want to pass relative paths that include the tilde around the application as strings, use the Url.Content helper to resolve them.
